# WinRT: Cannot read folders from LocalFolder

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am trying to create my own folder in the LocalFolder of my WinRT app and open it if it exists already:

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFolder accountFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("accounts", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

However, I get a System.ArgumentException:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Value does not fall within the expected range.

This exception does not occur if I use `CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName` instead. Also, I get the same exception when calling

```
localFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
```

so I guess reading folders is the problem. Am I lacking permissions to read from this location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution: Apparently, Windows has a problem with the folder being named "accounts". Changing the name solved the problem.